# Ruby map to json object and adding keys

Tags: json, ruby, dictionary

I got this ruby map

```
top_services = [["mfemve", "12,22"], ["vmtoolsd", "5,39"], ["zabbix_agentd", "1,89"]]
```

I need to convert this map to a JSON object and add keys something like this

```
{   
   { "service_name" : "mfemve", "value" : "12,22" },
   { "service_name" : "vmtoolsd", "value" : "5,39" },
   { "service_name" : "zabbix_agentd", "value" : "1,89" }   
}
```

how can I do this?
thanks!

Comment: Your JSON object is incorrect because "Data is in name/value pairs". Check at https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: The top and bottom curly brackets `{ ... }` should probably be square brackets `[ ... ]`, since it looks like you want an array of objects. I'm also not convinced that you want JSON. A lot of novice programmers throw the term JSON around as soon as they encounter a structure like `{ "key": "value" }`. Although this example is valid JSON, it might not be JSON and could as well be a Ruby hash (depending on context). Are you sure you want a [string containing a JSON object](/q/2904131/3982562)? Or do you want a [Ruby hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Hash.html) that matches the given format?

Answer (score 0):

You need the [json module](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.2/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html), then [mapping](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Array.html#method-i-map) using [zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Array.html#method-i-zip) you can do this:

```
require 'json'

top_services = [["mfemve", "12,22"], ["vmtoolsd", "5,39"], ["zabbix_agentd", "1,89"]]

keys = [:service_name, :value]
res = top_services.map { |e| keys.zip(e).to_h }.to_json

res
#=> "[{\"service_name\":\"mfemve\",\"value\":\"12,22\"},{\"service_name\":\"vmtoolsd\",\"value\":\"5,39\"},{\"service_name\":\"zabbix_agentd\",\"value\":\"1,89\"}]"
```

Consider to review the decimal separator of your numeric data, just in case it is a float.